# java - Modifying member variable causes line to be skipped

Tags: java

**Closing** It looks like it's related to the IDE (Eclipse). I built a separate class with the same code and different name and it works fine. Tried cleaning, restarting etc. Ugh.

**Updated test code** I'm stumped here and I'm guessing it's something stupid. I've whittled my code down to this which reproduces the issue.

This executes `mMemberVar = 2;` and then causes the `return now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);` to be skipped. It then skips to `return null;`

Is this caused by it being `Serializable` and something strange with modifying it's own member variables? I can't find anything on it.

```
public class Alarm implements Serializable {
    int mMemberVar = 0;
    public Calendar nextTime() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (true) {
            if (true) {
                if (true) {
                    mMemberVar = 2;
                    // return is skipped
                    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
                    return now;
                }
            }
            now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);
            return now;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry everyone. My mistake with the now.add(...). I 've fixed my test code, but it still persists. I've cleaned and rebuilt as well.

Comment: @Kirk sorry, but I can't reproduce the problem. See this: http://ideone.com/fCIaO . Try adding `System.out.println("Hello world!");` at the beginning of that method to make sure the code is compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your IDE didn't even recompile the code you wrote here. I'm guessing that because [Calendar.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) does not return anything, so the code you are showing can not be compiled at all.

So basically, you are running an old version of code which always returns null. Try doing "clean" then "rebuild" or similar action in your IDE.

Comment: It looks like it's related to the IDE (Eclipse). I built a separate class with the same code and different name and it works fine. Tried cleaning, restarting etc. You're probably right, just need to figure out how to clean it totally

Answer (score 3):

The `add` method of Calendar returns `void`. You should put the `add(...)` before the return line and `return now;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can have code like below... add returns void...

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Alarm implements Serializable {
    int mMemberVar = 0;
    public Calendar nextTime() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (true) {
            if (true) {
                if (true) {
                    mMemberVar = 2;
                    // return is skipped
                    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
                    return now;
                }
            }
            now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);
            return now;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```